# How Will the Inclusion of Two Forms Affect my CSRF Token Use?

Tags: django, post, django-csrf

I am attempting to create a page that includes two forms: one that is visible when the page loads (a signin form), and a second that appears in a modal if the user clicks a button (a signup form).

I am using Django, and, although I am still figuring out how I will handle these forms, my largest concern is how the CSRF token will play into all of this. For example, should I use `{% csrf_token %}` inside of only one of my `<form></form>` tags, or should I place it in both?

Further, if I do use it in both forms, will this affect my POSTS to the server in any way? Currently, I am taking the data in a form (depending on which submit button is clicked) and POSTing this way:

```
var data={
    'username':$('#username').val(), 
    'password':$('#password').val(),
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
}

$.post("/", signin_data);
```

Comment: you should place it in both as long as both are being accessed on the server side via `GET` or `POST` and YES you can place it in both without any issues

Comment: Perfect. @karthikr I would appreciate if you could respond to this as an answer so that I could mark it as correct. In addition, could you include how I would access the csrf token? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`csrf_token` should be placed in both the forms, as long as both are being accessed on the server side via `GET` or `POST`, and YES you **can** use the same `csrf_token` for both the forms without any issues.

You can do something like

```
<form action="." >{% csrf_token %}
    {{form1.as_p}}
</form>
```

when you do `data=form.serialize()`, the `csrf` token is automatically serialized in the `data` of the ajax request.

The reason multiple `{% csrf_token %}` works is because all the token does is provide information for validation that a form request is from a valid (untampered) user session.